# python social auth UserSocialAuth is not json serializable

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I am using python social auth for django social authentication. I have written a custom pipeline for sending email. Everything works fine just at the section of sending email it gives me UserSocialAuth is not json serializable error.

Can anyone guide me why I am getting this error ?
How to get rid of it ?

Comment: Can you post the code of your partial pipeline?

Comment: I have fixed it.. thank you..

Comment: great! now you can answer your own question and accept it

Answer (score 0):

you should use:

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

in settings.py